# GRE: Can area of this parallelogram be known given one interior angle and the lengths of two adjacent sides?

Tags: geometry, area, quadrilateral

[image]

A GRE question asks whether the area of parallelogram can be found only using the information provided above.

Area of parallelogram = base x height

If we cut off one end to form a triangle and place it on the end, we would get a rectangle that looks like:

[image]

But we still do not know the width of rectangle in order to calculate area. Can we assume that not enough information is provided?

Comment: Isn't the width $6\sin(x)$?

Comment: Is $x$ to be considered known?

Comment: 'x' is stated to be less than 90 degrees. Otherwise, no other information on it.

Comment: About your last, deleted question, no, your answer is not correct; be careful: you still need to count the shoes. It's $4\times 3\times 2- 2$.

Comment: @Shaun Right, I felt like something was off with my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assume that. Just try two different $x$ values to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

Area $A=54sin(x)$. Without knowing x we cannot find the area.